# Why most block use argument for iteration continue flag instead of return value?

Tags: ios, frameworks, objective-c-blocks

For most iteration blocks, signatures are defined sort of:

```
void(^)(id obj, BOOL* stop)
```

It looks better using return value for stopping flag.

```
BOOL(^)(id obj)
```

However I believe there is a strong reason made them to decide to use current form instead of more short and convenient form. Why do they use argument for stop flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it would work fine either way, but think of it this way: do you have to use the `continue` statement at the end of your `for` or `while` loop? No, of course not because it happens automatically. If you want to stop looping though, you can just use `break`.

Similarly with the block-based enumeration methods. You're not required to return `YES` to specify whether you want to continue enumeration or not because it will happen automatically. However, if you want to stop enumerating, you can simply set `*stop` to `YES`.